# Scala reading from csv file

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to read a column from csv file. The problem I'm getting is"

```
org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.parser.ParseException: 
mismatched input ''s'' expecting <EOF>(line 1, pos 18)
```

The data in the column is written like this:
"""Dental by Design"""

So when I try to read from the column I keep getting the error above. My code is:

```
val businessName = business.filter("name == 'mcdonald's'")
```

Comment: Try an update "name == mcdonald's ". Also can you please post sample records of input csv which you are using.

Comment: No, that didn't work. This is how the data is written:  """Dental by Design"""

Comment: How about `val businessName = business.filter("name == 'mcdonald\'s'")`

Comment: No, sill it didn't work

Comment: Try this: val businessName = business.filter("""name == "mcdonald's" """)

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
scala> val business = Seq(("mcdonald's"),("srinivas"),("ravi")).toDF("name")
business: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [name: string]

scala> business.filter($"name" === """mcdonald's""").show
+----------+
|      name|
+----------+
|mcdonald's|
+----------+
```

Comment: val businessName = business.filter("name" === """mcdonald's""")

Comment: You have to add $ or col function before name column

Comment: I didn't need to add $ before when I use it with a different column that worked